# Density as a function of Temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, mass, temperature, density, volume

I know that volume = mass/density....and density is the function of temperature.

Is there any standard equation that describes density as a function of temperature?

The system I am interested in is like a liquid tank or reservoir

Comment: For what system? For an ideal gas you have the equation of state $PV = nRT$ so the molar density is $n/V = P/RT$. For other systems there will be corresponding but more complicated expressions.

Comment: @JohnRennie      this is definitely not gas, but liquid (fuel). Is it something like empirical set of values under different temperature and done through lookup table? Or is there any actual formula. I know that different fuel types will have different density numbers (based on different temperature).

Comment: I'm sure there is an empirical formula for the density of gasoline as a function of temperature, but I don't know it offhand. I expect a quick Google would find it.

Comment: @hagubear: There is no general formula applicable to all liquids. However, if you are interested in one particular commonly-used liquid, Wojciech's answer is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know density $\rho_r$ at some temperature $T_r$, there is a following formula for density:

$\rho=\rho_r[1+b(T-T_r)]$,

where $\rho$ is the density at temperature $T$ and $b$ is called coefficient of cubical expansion, evaluated at reference temperature and density ($\rho_r$ and $T_r$).

This is a linear approximation, valid for narrow temperature ranges -- more generally, the dependence of density on the temperature and pressure (equation of state) is any complicated function due to the internal structure of matter: for water, it's not even monotonically decreasing with temperature!Statistical mechanics describes procedures to approximate the equation of state for a given model of a material, but it's usually not expressible analytically in any human readable equation (a notable exception is the gas equation). Usually, relations are measured and either interpolated from tables, or fitted with a polynomial/rational function.

Comment: I think $rho_r$ should be DIVIDED, NOT MULTIPLIED by $beta(T - T)$

Comment: Why You think so?

Comment: because volume = mass/density....and if the temperature increases, volume increases and density decreases... http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/volumetric-temperature-expansion-d_315.html

Comment: In such case the coefficient of cubical expansion b is negative and the formula is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

As we know, temperature and density have a relation because of the knowledge we know from the kinetic nature of matter. If we know the density of any fluid and its current temperature,

ρ = ρr [1 - β(T – Tr)]

Where ρr and Tr is the reference density and pressure respectively. It is best to take the values at either RTP(293K) or STP(273K).

There is a negative sign within the brackets of the equation as the relationship between temperature and density is inversely proportional. Along with this, you subtract the initial density with the change in density due to the temperature difference. When the fluid undergoes a temperature change, the coefficient of volumetric expansion will fall into place as the temperature provides kinetic energy and with enough of this energy, the liquid can expand. Thus by subtracting the quantities within the brackets, we can find out the temperature change. This is usually applied with smaller temperature ranges.

Hope this helps. I have also added a website in which this formula is used to calculate the final temperature for benzene for any temperature you input. Although it does not mention it while calculating, you can manually calculate this and your answer will match with the calculation done by the site.

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/benzene-benzol-density-specific-weight-temperaure-pressure-d_2057.html?vA=80&degree=C#